# Что делать? Меняются стили кнопки на Safari IOS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, кроссбраузерность, кроссплатформенность

Меняются стили input на Safari IOS. Прописал вендорные префиксы , не работает. 1 Кнопка на Chrome Android , а вторая на Safari IOS.

Что делать? Как решить данную проблему?

[image: Андроид Хром]

[image: Сафари IOS]

Answer (score 1):

Добавь свойство `-webkit-appearance: none;`. Тоже помню как-то страдал.

Answer (score 1):

Свойство `appearance` используется для отображения элемента с использованием платформенного стиля, основанного на теме операционной системы пользователя. И мы его убираем. Также убираем фокус, какой есть на safari и Google Chrome.

```
   .btn, button{
       -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance:    none;
       appearance:         none;
    }
    
    .btn:focus, button:focus{
      outline: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ставьте к своим стилям этот `reset.css` и проблема отпадет. Сам пользовался `normalize.css` и была такая проблема. В этом `reset` прописано все, что надо.

[reset.css](https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6#file-reset-css)